# Passing value from multiple textbox to string on another form or calling the value/string from textbox from another form

Tags: c#, .net

I have searched high and low and I find almost what i need. I need to be able to get the values from form1's textboxes into a string and used in form4 to run something like a copy command or storescp in my case.
example:
           Form1:
           Public static string port1
           port1 = Pt1.text;
           dicompath = location.text;

```
       Form4:
        port1 = frm1.Port1.Text;
        dicompath = frm1.location.text;

        finalpath = port1 + " --fork -v -pm -fe .dcm -tn -sp -od " + ((char)34) + dicompath + ((char)34);

        Process startInfo2 = new Process();
        startInfo2.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        startInfo2.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo2.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        startInfo2.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        startInfo2.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo2.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\dcmtk\bin\storescp-tls.exe";
        startInfo2.StartInfo.Arguments = finalpath;
        startInfo2.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
```

For some reason,  I keep getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Which part of your code is `not set to an instance of an object`? Your Q is a bit vague to me. User inputs a value on form1, and you want to use that value on form4? Or do you want to combine a user entered value on form1 with another user entered value on form 4 in order to run something later on?

Comment: I have about 4-6 textbox that I need to (not combine) store in their own variable that can be called from another form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I read your question, your asking how to pass a user entered value from one form to another. So here is a minimal example that shows you the basic concepts of doing so.
Basically, you *just need* to make a form constructor that will accept parameters. You can then instantiate your extra form with this new constructor to use the value you are passing around.

In this snippet, I'm passing a value from Form1 to Form2 using `Form2 form2 = new Form2(theText);`

Form1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PassValuesBetweenForms_43923548
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CreateTextBox();
            CreateSubmitButton();
        }

        private void CreateSubmitButton()
        {
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Text = "click me";
            btn.Click += ClickMeGotClicked;
            btn.Location = new Point(5, 25);
            this.Controls.Add(btn);
        }

        private void ClickMeGotClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string theText = ((TextBox)this.Controls["txtbx"]).Text;
            Form2 form2 = new Form2(theText);//call the parametized constructor
            form2.Show();
        }

        private void CreateTextBox()
        {
            TextBox tb = new TextBox();
            tb.Location = new Point(5, 5);
            tb.Width = 50;
            tb.Name = "txtbx";
            this.Controls.Add(tb);
        }
    }
}
```

Form2.cs

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PassValuesBetweenForms_43923548
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //make a parametized constructor
        public Form2(string incomingFromForm1)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(incomingFromForm1))
            {
                MakeALabelWithThis(incomingFromForm1);
            }
        }

        private void MakeALabelWithThis(string incomingFromForm1)
        {
            Label lbl = new Label();
            lbl.Text = incomingFromForm1;
            lbl.Location = new Point(5,5);
            this.Controls.Add(lbl);
        }
    }
}
```