# C# How do I copy a selected datagridview row's value from one form to a datagridview's row on another form?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, html-agility-pack

I'm using html agility pack to get the data for the grid view. I simply want to copy a row using a column button to send it to a blank grid view on another form. There is no data bindings or SQL. After populating the grid I am getting the entire data grid view without pushing the column button. The code I have is:

Form 1

```
private void LeadsDataGridView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    Database DB = new Database(LeadsDataGridView.DataSource);

    var senderGrid = (DataGridView)sender;

    if (senderGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonColumn && e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        DB.Row = LeadsDataGridView.CurrentRow;
    }

    Search_Table.AcceptChanges();

    LeadsDataGridView.DataSource = Search_Table;
}
```

Form 2

```
public Database(object DataSource)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    InitDBTable();
    DB_GridView.DataSource = DataSource;
}
```

Comment: [Using this method should work fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43923548/passing-value-from-multiple-textbox-to-string-on-another-form-or-calling-the-val/43924222#43924222). That SO post is about passing a String but, you can pass anything for as long as your method is expecting the parameter type you intend to pass it.

Comment: datagridview != wpf datagrid != gridview. which one of them are you using?

Comment: Perhaps, its too broad of a question. How would you copy the value of a single datagridview's row to another datagridview if the values for each column were simply typed in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a minimal example that will hopefully get you on your way.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="PassingValuesFromFormToForm_45425412.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PassingValuesFromFormToForm_45425412"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="61,60,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="259"/>
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="29,13,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;

namespace PassingValuesFromFormToForm_45425412
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        List<dgvEntry> dgvList = new List<dgvEntry>();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dgvList.Add(new PassingValuesFromFormToForm_45425412.dgvEntry { col1 = "blah blah", col2 = "blehbleh" });
            dataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            dataGrid.ItemsSource = dgvList;
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Window1 win1 = new Window1((dgvEntry)dataGrid.Items[0]);
            win1.Show();
        }
    }

    public class dgvEntry {
        public string col1 { get; set; }
        public string col2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Window1.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="PassingValuesFromFormToForm_45425412.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PassingValuesFromFormToForm_45425412"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="23,39,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="181"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Window1.xaml.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;

namespace PassingValuesFromFormToForm_45425412
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Window1(dgvEntry incomingItem)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            dataGrid.ItemsSource = new List<dgvEntry> { incomingItem };
        }
    }
}
```

**Here's an update for WinForms.** Again, this is a minimal example. For the purpose of this sample, I did nothing in Form designer. **Everything** is done through code behind.

**Form1.cs**

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
        BindingList<dgvitem> itemsList = new BindingList<dgvitem>();
        bool SendAsRow = true;//just a variable to trigger the proper method in 'Dgv_CellContentClick'
        Button independantButton = new Button();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeTheDGV();
            AddTheButton();
            itemsList.Add(new dgvitem { JustaTextField = "aksldjf sadfjasifuqw adsfasf" });
            itemsList.Add(new dgvitem { JustaTextField = "qwerioqu aisdfnvmz, oaa"});
        }

        private void InitializeTheDGV()
        {
            dgv.Location = new Point(this.Location.X + 5, this.Location.Y + 5);
            dgv.DataSource = itemsList;
            dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            this.Controls.Add(dgv);
            dgv.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() { HeaderText = "My col header", Name="mycol1" });
            dgv.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewButtonColumn() { HeaderText = "click in this column", Name = "mycol2" });
            dgv.Columns["mycol1"].DataPropertyName = "JustaTextField";
            dgv.CellContentClick += Dgv_CellContentClick;
        }

        private void Dgv_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!(sender is DataGridView))
            {
                return;
            }

            /*
             * Experiment and Pick your poison
             */
            if (SendAsRow)
            {
                Form2 f2r = new Form2(dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex]);
                f2r.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                Form2 f2 = new Form2((string)dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].FormattedValue);
                f2.Show();
            }
            /**/
        }


        private void AddTheButton()
        {
            independantButton.Location = new Point(this.Location.X + 5, this.Location.Y + dgv2.Height + 15);
            independantButton.Click += IndependantButton_Click;
            this.Controls.Add(independantButton);
        }

        private void IndependantButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            /*
             * Experiment and Pick your poison
             */
            if (SendAsRow)
            {
                Form2 f2r = new Form2(dgv.SelectedRows[0]);
                f2r.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                Form2 f2 = new Form2((string)dgv.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].FormattedValue);
                f2.Show();
            }
            /**/

        }
    }


    public class dgvitem
    {
        public string JustaTextField { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Form2.cs**

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        DataGridView dgv2 = new DataGridView();
        BindingList<dgv2item> dgv2list = new BindingList<dgv2item>();

        //this is the 'default' constructor which takes no argument
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MakeTheGrid();
        }

        //this form constructor takes a String parameter so you can pass only a string
        public Form2(string incomingText)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MakeTheGrid();
            dgv2list.Add(new dgv2item { coolBeans = incomingText });//add the incoming String to the itemList, which will in-turn update the DataGridView
        }


        //this form constructor takes a DataGridViewRow parameter so you can pass the whole row
        public Form2(DataGridViewRow incomingRow)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MakeTheGrid();
            dgv2list.Add(new dgv2item { coolBeans = (string)incomingRow.Cells[0].FormattedValue});//add the value of the cell you want out of the row to the itemlist, which will in-turn update the DataGridView
        }


        private void MakeTheGrid()
        {
            dgv2.Location = new Point(this.Location.X + 15, this.Location.Y + 15);//it has to go somewhere...
            dgv2.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            dgv2.DataSource = dgv2list;//define where to find the data
            this.Controls.Add(dgv2);//add it to the form
        }
    }


    public class dgv2item
    {
        public string coolBeans { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I Liked the example that you listed blaze_125. It helped me to see the logic behind what you think is the gist of my problem however; my program's code is so different than your example that I cannot make sense of what is happening within your code. I have tried to use: DB_Table.Rows.Add(Search_Table.Rows[e.RowIndex]); as a means of collecting the row however I get an error saying that "this row already belongs to another table" I am using a DataTable now with a DataSource. I will continue to do some research and try to find a solution. If I run across something I will post it here.

Comment: Please follow up to @ASh question in your opening post. The tags, and the content of your post are somewhat in contradiction. I gave you a WPF example but, it feels like you might actually be working with a Form rather than WPF. If you're indeed working with Forms, I'll write up another answer. To find out if you're working in WPF, look at the solution Explorer in Visual Studio. If you solution explorer has ".xaml" files listed, then you in a WPF project. If you don't have that file extension listed, then you're likely working in Forms.

Comment: You're right blaze_125, I apologize for the misunderstanding. I used an incorrect tag. You're code actually makes much more sense to me now. To answer ASh's question I'm using a DataGridView with a DataTable and "get" "set" variables within a DataPile class. I'm generating the data within the DGV after running a search of the criteria. The copy button is within the DGV as a column. I have a separate button to open the form. I'm using FullRowSelect for the selection mode.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I updated my answer with code that should help you understand the task at hand.

Comment: +1 Thanks blaze_125. That is exactly the code and logic I was looking to acquire. It turns out I was missing BindingList<DataPile> DB_GridViewList = new BindingList<DataPile>(); You just saved my life on this deadline. I'm new to the business application world. As you can see by my name I mostly dabble in game addons using java or LUA. sometimes I will use c# with Unity, again much appreciated. Cheers!